# Change order of xmlns attribute

Tags: java, xml, xml-namespaces

I know that in XML the order of attributes should´t mind, but in my particular case i really need to be consistent with the order of the original XML documents (for example, to correctly validate some XML signatures).

I´m having some problems when getting some node of the original document and adding a clone of this node to a newly created document. The problem is that i´m signing the original node which declares a namespace before the version attribute but then when i retrieve that node again from other part of the code the order of the version and namespace declaration attributes changes. I would like them to stay the same as the original because i need to validate the signature. This is what is happening right now:

Original Signed Doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><ns0:CF xmlns:ns0="http://someurl.com" version="1.0">
    <ns0:EF>...
```

Node to validate from original doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><ns0:CF version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://someurl.com">
    <ns0:EF>...
```

I need to keep the order of the version and xmlns attributes, like they appear in the original document.

I have tried a lot of things but neither of them seems to work... thank you and excuse my english!

Comment: Tools that generate XML signatures should cope with canonicalization issues like this. How are you generating the signature?

Comment: I still Really Wish that XML signatures had been defined in terms of the infoset rather than the text representation thereof, so things that Do Not Matter (like attribute order) didn't pollute the signature result...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using DecentXML:
https://code.google.com/p/decentxml/

I used it once to implement a configuration tool that had to update existing XML without changing existing formatting and had to output the attributes in a human-friendly order. It worked pretty well in my case.